# How to prove that infinite number of pentagons exist satisfying the given requirements

Tags: geometry

A given convex pentagon ABCDE has the property that the area of each of the 5 triangles ABC, BCD, CDE, DEA and EAB are equal. How can I prove that there exist infinitely many non-congruent pentagons having the above property? I tried to take one side of the triangle as fixed and build upon it but I couldn't do anything as I couldn't determine the angle of the pentagon. Any help please

Comment: what about similar pentagons? There are infinitely many of those and because the ratio of sides will be the same the corresponding triangles will have the same area.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The regular pentagon has this property. Any invertible affine transformation
of the plane has the property that equal areas are sent to equal areas. So
for instance we can stretch the regular pentagon by a given scale factor in the
$x$-direction (but leave the scale in the $y$-direction unchanged) to get an infinite family of non-congruent pentagons with your area property.

Comment: I'd say the interesting question is whether any pentagon with these five triangles having the same area must be affinely equivalent to the regular pentagon.

Comment: Thanks I got your point. Is it possible to do the same thing if in all the pentagons I want to have a fixed value, say one for the area of the 5 triangles I have mentioned in the question? I don't think its possible to do so right?

Comment: @saisathenjeev Of course that is possible: take the regular pentagon, scale it by a factor $\mu$ in the $x$-direction and by $1/\mu$ in the $y$-direction.